Highlighting specific roads on OSM with QGIS
I'm currently creating a university project on QGIS. I need to highlight, on an OSM map of the UK, the historical route of the Great Northern Road. I have tried adding UK road network shp files but these are obviously far too broad and my attempts to filter the data to just show the roads I need have been unsuccessful.
I'm very new to the QGIS software.

This route? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_North_Road_(Great_Britain)#/media/File:Great-north-road-uk.png

If you have the entire road system in a shapefile .shp, you could just highlight/select the features that you want to keep by using the select tool ant the Ctrl button and then export them to a new file.

Data extracted from sabre-roads wiki

According to this link the road is named A1 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A1_road_(Great_Britain) . Open the road attribute table and search by attribute A1 it will be highlighted.

Data extracted from
https://www.sabre-roads.org.uk/wiki/index.php?title=A1
[Society for All British and Irish Road Enthusiasts]

Shapefile https://filetransfer.io/data-package/4gtzILLU#link
(link will expire)
